# Kerberos and brute-force attacks

Tags: passwords, brute-force, password-cracking, kerberos

Suppose that I am the administrator of a system that uses Kerberos and password authentication.  How can I make brute-force attacks on user’s passwords by an attacker who can capture network traffic difficult?

Ideally, I would use a protocol such as SRP, but Kerberos doesn’t support that.